# Area of a closed contour on a plot using python openCV

Tags: python, opencv, contour

I am attempting to find the area inside an arbitrarily-shaped closed curve plotted in python (example image below). So far, I have tried to use both the alphashape and polygon methods to acheive this, but both have failed. I am now attempting to use OpenCV and the floodfill method to count the number of pixels inside the curve and then I will later convert that to an area given the area that a single pixel encloses on the plot.
Example image:
[testplot.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLIjM.jpg)

In order to do this, I am doing the following, which I adapted from another post about OpenCV.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Input image
img = cv2.imread('testplot.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

# Dilate to better detect contours
temp = cv2.dilate(temp, cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (3, 3)))

# Find largest contour
cnts, _ = cv2.findContours(255-temp, cv2.RETR_TREE , cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE) #255-img and cv2.RETR_TREE is to account for how cv2 expects the background to be black, not white, so I convert the background to black.
largestCnt = [] #I expect this to yield the blue contour
for cnt in cnts:
    if (len(cnt) > len(largestCnt)):
        largestCnt = cnt

# Determine center of area of largest contour
M = cv2.moments(largestCnt)
x = int(M["m10"] / M["m00"])
y = int(M["m01"] / M["m00"])

# Initial mask for flood filling, should cover entire figure
width, height = temp.shape
mask = img2 = np.ones((width + 2, height + 2), np.uint8) * 255
mask[1:width, 1:height] = 0

# Generate intermediate image, draw largest contour onto it, flood fill this contour
temp = np.zeros(temp.shape, np.uint8)
temp = cv2.drawContours(temp, largestCnt, -1, 255, cv2.FILLED)
_, temp, mask, _ = cv2.floodFill(temp, mask, (x, y), 255)
temp = cv2.morphologyEx(temp, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (3, 3)))

area = cv2.countNonZero(temp) #Number of pixels encircled by blue line
```

I expect from this to get to a place where I have the same image as above, but with the center of the contour filled in white and the background and original blue contour in black. I end up with this:

[result.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sCUZS.jpg)

While this at first glance appears to have accurately turned the area inside the contour white, the white area is actually larger than the area inside the contour and so the result I get is overestimating the number of pixels inside it.
Any input on this would be greatly appreciated. I am fairly new to OpenCV so I may have misunderstood something.

EDIT:
Thanks to a comment below, I made some edits and this is now my code, with edits noted:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# EDITED INPUT IMAGE: Input image
img = cv2.imread('testplot2.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

# EDIT: threshold
_, temp = cv2.threshold(img, 250, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

# EDIT, REMOVED: Dilate to better detect contours

# Find largest contour
cnts, _ = cv2.findContours(temp, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL , cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
largestCnt = [] #I expect this to yield the blue contour
for cnt in cnts:
    if (len(cnt) > len(largestCnt)):
        largestCnt = cnt

# Determine center of area of largest contour
M = cv2.moments(largestCnt)
x = int(M["m10"] / M["m00"])
y = int(M["m01"] / M["m00"])


# Initial mask for flood filling, should cover entire figure
width, height = temp.shape
mask = img2 = np.ones((width + 2, height + 2), np.uint8) * 255
mask[1:width, 1:height] = 0

# Generate intermediate image, draw largest contour, flood filled
temp = np.zeros(temp.shape, np.uint8)
temp = cv2.drawContours(temp, largestCnt, -1, 255, cv2.FILLED)
_, temp, mask, _ = cv2.floodFill(temp, mask, (x, y), 255)
temp = cv2.morphologyEx(temp, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (3, 3)))

area = cv2.countNonZero(temp) #Number of pixels encircled by blue line
```

I input a different [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aA2HO.jpg) with the axes and the frame that python adds by default removed for ease. I get what I expect at the second step, so [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p2He5.jpg). However, in the [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gAwkY.jpg) both the original contour and the area it encircles appear to have been made white, whereas I want the original contour to be black and only the area it encircles to be white. How might I acheive this?

Comment: Seems to me that if you convert to grayscale and threshold so that the curve is white and the exterior is black, you should be able to use cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL in findContours and then get its cv2.contourArea. Contours works best with binary images. If that does not work for you, let me know and I will coding that myself.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer! I modified the script a little but it does not appear to work yet. I will edit my question so you see what I am doing now and the result I am getting

Comment: You do not need all the moments and flood filling. You can simply get the contours and then cv2.contour(area) should give you what you want. But be sure that the outline is white and the background is black after you threshold. You may need to invert your thresholded image. View it to be sure. If you need to see it as white filled on black, then create a new black image the size of input and then draw a white filled contour on it using drawContours() and set the line thickness to -1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your `opening` operation at the end. This morphological operation includes a `dilation` at the end that expands the white contour, increasing its area. Let’s try a different approach where no morphology is involved. These are the steps:

1. Convert your image to **grayscale**
2. Apply **Otsu’s thresholding** to get a **binary image**, let’s work with black and white pixels only.
3. Apply a first **flood-fill** operation at image location `(0,0)` to get rid of the outer white space.
4. **Filter** small blobs using an area filter
5. Find the “Curve Canvas” (The white space that encloses the curve) and locate and store its starting point at `(targetX, targetY)`
6. Apply a second **flood-fill** al location `(targetX, targetY)`
7. Get the **area** of the isolated blob with `cv2.countNonZero`

Let’s take a look at the code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Set image path
path = "C:/opencvImages/"
fileName = "cLIjM.jpg"

# Read Input image
inputImage = cv2.imread(path+fileName)
inputCopy = inputImage.copy()

# Convert BGR to grayscale:
grayscaleImage = cv2.cvtColor(inputImage, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Threshold via Otsu + bias adjustment:
threshValue, binaryImage = cv2.threshold(grayscaleImage, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
```

This is the binary image you get:

[image]

Now, let’s `flood-fill` at the corner located at `(0,0)` with a black color to get rid of the first white space. This step is very straightforward:

```
# Flood-fill background, seed at (0,0) and use black color:
cv2.floodFill(binaryImage, None, (0, 0), 0)
```

This is the result, note how the first big white area is gone:

[image]

Let’s get rid of the small blobs applying an **area filter**. Everything below an area of `100` is gonna be deleted:

```
# Perform an area filter on the binary blobs:
componentsNumber, labeledImage, componentStats, componentCentroids = \
cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(binaryImage, connectivity=4)

# Set the minimum pixels for the area filter:
minArea = 100

# Get the indices/labels of the remaining components based on the area stat
# (skip the background component at index 0)
remainingComponentLabels = [i for i in range(1, componentsNumber) if componentStats[i][4] >= minArea]

# Filter the labeled pixels based on the remaining labels,
# assign pixel intensity to 255 (uint8) for the remaining pixels
filteredImage = np.where(np.isin(labeledImage, remainingComponentLabels) == True, 255, 0).astype('uint8')
```

This is the result of the filter:

[image]

Now, what remains is the second white area, I need to locate its starting point because I want to apply a second `flood-fill` operation at this location. I’ll traverse the image to find the first white pixel. Like this:

```
# Get Image dimensions:
height, width = filteredImage.shape

# Store the flood-fill point here:
targetX = -1
targetY = -1

for i in range(0, width):
    for j in range(0, height):
        # Get current binary pixel:
        currentPixel = filteredImage[j, i]
        # Check if it is the first white pixel:
        if targetX == -1 and targetY == -1 and currentPixel == 255:
            targetX = i
            targetY = j

print("Flooding in X = "+str(targetX)+" Y: "+str(targetY))
```

There’s probably a more elegant, `Python`-oriented way of doing this, but I’m still learning the language. Feel free to improve the script (and share it here). The loop, however, gets me the location of the first white pixel, so I can now apply a second `flood-fill` at this exact location:

```
# Flood-fill background, seed at (targetX, targetY) and use black color:
cv2.floodFill(filteredImage, None, (targetX, targetY), 0)
```

You end up with this:

[image]

As you see, just count the number of non-zero pixels:

```
# Get the area of the target curve:
area = cv2.countNonZero(filteredImage)

print("Curve Area is: "+str(area))
```

The result is:

```
Curve Area is: 1510
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! I'll give this a go. Have a great weekend. EDIT: It's working! Thank you!

Comment: @Ariane No problem, my friend. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach using Python/OpenCV.

- Read Input
- convert to HSV colorspace
- Threshold on color range of blue
- Find the largest contour
- Get its area and print that
- draw the contour as a white filled contour on black background
- Save the results

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read image as grayscale
img = cv2.imread('closed_curve.jpg')

# convert to HSV
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

#select blu color range in hsv
lower = (24,128,115)
upper = (164,255,255)

# threshold on blue in hsv
thresh = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower, upper)

# get largest contour
contours = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
contours = contours[0] if len(contours) == 2 else contours[1]
big_contour = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)
area = cv2.contourArea(c)
print("Area =",area)

# draw filled contour on black background
result = np.zeros_like(thresh)
cv2.drawContours(result, [c], -1, 255, cv2.FILLED)

# save result
cv2.imwrite("closed_curve_thresh.jpg", thresh)
cv2.imwrite("closed_curve_result.jpg", result)

# view result
cv2.imshow("threshold", thresh)
cv2.imshow("result", result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Threshold Image:

[image]

Result Filled Contour On Black Background:

[image]

Area Result:

Area = 2347.0

Comment: Thank you for your assistance! How did you fill the contour when you drew it on to the image at the end? I am doing what you are, only with [c] replaced with bigContour because [c] threw an undefined error. Also, what is c? I don't see it defined in your code and I'm curious. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: `cv2.drawContours(result, [c], -1, 255, cv2.FILLED)`  The command says cv2.FILLED.  That is what fills the contour. You can use -1 for that same field, which is the line thickness for the contour.